# Creating the following page in latex

Tags: thesis, front-matter

I am done with my thesis. I am trying to replicate the following thesis page in latex. I am having a lot of hard time doing it. [image]

I tried the following code but it is giving me the same look

```
$ 
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{ 
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\vspace*{\fill} 
\vspace{100pt} 
\begin{center} 
\Huge {title} \normalsize \\ 
\vspace{25pt} 
Namel\\ 
\vspace{135pt} 
\textsc{a thesis submitted in partial fulfillment\\ 
of the requirements for the degree of \\ 
\vspace{8pt} 
degree \\ 
department \\ 
university \\ 
\vspace{10pt} 
degreemonth, degreeyear} 
\end{center} 
\vspace*{\fill} }$
```

Comment: what you try so far? which document class you use? some document classes provide style for title page.

Comment: I am not good with latex. I am using documentclass{article}.

Comment: I tried the following code but it is giving me the same look @Zarko.
$
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \vspace*{\fill}
 \vspace{100pt}
 \begin{center}
 \Huge {title} \normalsize \\
 \vspace{25pt}
 Namel\\
 \vspace{135pt}
 \textsc{a thesis submitted in partial fulfillment\\
 of the requirements for the degree of \\
 \vspace{8pt}
 degree \\
 department \\
 university \\
 \vspace{10pt}
 degreemonth, degreeyear}
 \end{center}
 \vspace*{\fill}
}$

Comment: (i) i took a  liberty and move code from your comment to your question, (ii) meanwhile you receive an answer. (iii) for thesis the document class `article` is not appropriate choice,more appropriate is to use `report` or `book` or similar classes (iv) many universities provide own "template" for thesis or provide advice, which one of  "public"  to use.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280 and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typeset the front page you show in your request is very simple. I will post my approach, but you must understand there's several forms to achieve the desired format.

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}

   Enter Thesis title\par
   \vfill
   by\par
   \vfill
   Enter Student's Full Name\par
   \vspace{1.5in}

   A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of\par
   \vfill
   Enter/select Full Degree name\par
   \vfill
   [in\par
   \vfill
   INSERT OFFICIAL DESCRIPTION OF SPECIALIZATION, if applicable]\par
   \vspace{1.5in}
   Enter/select the name of your Department\par
   \vfill
   \end{center}

\end{document}
```